# ProFTPD multiple users with super user

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, proftpd

I have a question on ProFTPD. Is it possible to create a super user that can access all other ftp users ftp home directory?

For example, say we have `SuperUser`, `user1`, `user2`, `user3`, the user home directories is contained inside the `SuperUser` home directory

`/home/SuperUser/`
`/home/SuperUser/user1`
`/home/SuperUser/user2`
`/home/SuperUser/user3`

Now, `SuperUser` can access everything inside `/home/SuperUser/` but is jail locked to this directory. and `user1`, `user2`, `user3` are all jail locked to 
`user1` - `/home/SuperUser/user1`
`user2` - `/home/SuperUser/user2`
`user3` - `/home/SuperUser/user3`

I know you can jail lock all users by modifying `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` and changing this line

```
# Use this to jail all users in their homes
DefaultRoot                     ~
```

I already have 1 user that should access everything and my ftp connection works fine, but my secondary user, whose home directory is inside the first users home directory cannot use FTP

From the ftp client (FileZilla) I get this error when logging in with this user

```
Response:   550 PWD: Permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

If I move the home directory to `/home` (default option) then it works but my super user cannot access those files.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

I played with the configuration a bit an had to change the normal users file ownership to the user and SuperUser, then in the proftpd configuration for each user, in `/etc/proftpd/conf.d/user.conf` I had to allow both the normal user and the SuperUser to access that directory